# How to fetch all list titles in editor part of web part?

Tags: web-part, web-services, custom-web-part-property

I want to fetch all the list titles of the current site in a dropdown in my web part's editor part. Based on this selection I want to show list items in web part when Apply is hit.

My web part is deployed at site collections level.

Answer (score 1):

Get the List title source:

```
public static IList<String> GetAllListTitle(SPWeb web)
{
    List<String> title = new List<String>();

    foreach(SPList list in web.Lists)
      title.Items.Add(list.Title)
}
```

Have a look at these for how to implement dynamic dropdown as webpart property.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/d52e2e1b-5938-43c0-9708-8d9d710880ae/custom-web-part-properties-in-sharepoint-2010-visual-web-partsdynamic-dropdown

http://dev-tips.blogspot.in/2007/06/custom-property-of-webpart-dynamic.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to populate the dropdown list.

```
    SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
    foreach(SPList list in web.Lists)
    {
    dropdownList.Items.Add(list.Title)
    }
```